# How to send array of price-infos in foreach loop to external PHP as POST data with Ajax and back into each product price div?

Tags: php, ajax, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have a product view in my Virtuemart shop with a list of products. 
These products are generated by a foreach loop. Here is an example of how the product list could look like in the PHP code:

```
<div id="products">
<?php //Loop START
$counter = 0;
foreach ( $this->products as $product ) { 
$ProductName = $product->product_name;
$ProductID = $product->virtuemart_product_id;
$ProductSalesPrice = $product->prices['salesPrice'];
$ProductDiscount = $product->prices['discountAmount']; ?>
<div class="product">
<div class="nameHeader <?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $ProductName ?></div>
<div class="productID <?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $ProductID ?></div>
<div ID="salesprice<?php echo $counter ?>" class="salesprice <?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $ProductSalesPrice ?></div>
<div ID="discount<?php echo $counter ?>" class="discount <?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $ProductDiscount ?></div>
</div>
<?php $counter++; } //Loop END ?>
</div>
```

I´m looking for a way to show the price data with ajax instead of "static" PHP code, so that the prices are not cached by the Joomla component "JotCache".

I know how to do this with a single product by using ajax and sending the product ID to an PHP script as POST data, but I don´t know how to do this in an entire loop of products like the example above.

Does anyone know how to:

1. Send all the product-ID´s of the products in the loop to an external PHP script as POST data.
2. Retrieve all the calculated price data (sales prices and discounts based on product IDs) from the PHP script and populate each product´s sales price and discount inside the div-tags with the IDs e.g. "salesprice0" and "discount0", "salesprice1" and "discount1".. and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep product id as string with comma(,) separated like (123,456,789) and send it to your ajax page.

On ajax page, use PHP function explode to convert into array and fetched price of products.

And keep that all product price into a string, like (123:20:15,456:40:30,789:50:35)

use javascript function split by comma(,) so that single product id and price will convert into array. 

`Array(`

```
[0]=>123:20:15,
[1]=>456:40:30,
[2]=>789:50:35
```

)

Now again perform same javascript split function by (:) with each array value then array will create like

```
Array(
[0]=>123,
[1]=>20,
[2]=>15
)
```

Hope it will help

Comment: It looks very promising, thanks. I will give it a go ASAP and tell you how it went:)

Comment: Hi again, 
Your guidance has helped me quite a bit, but I´m stuck at the point where I need to take the calculated price information from the PHP script and apply each price to each product´s div tag ID.
This is the jQuery for the ajax POST call:

Comment: So instead of `relatedproductscustom.html( data );` I need to insert the data into multiple variables - being all the div tag IDs e.g. 
salesprice0, salesprice1 ..etc. and
discount0, discount1 ..etc.

Comment: //Related Products

`var relatedproductscustom = jQuery("#salesprice0");
  jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {productIDs:relatedproductsdata.products},
   url: "/CustomCodes/js/VM/related-creator2.php",
   success: function(data){
    jQuery('#salesprice0').css('display','none');
    //if(data == "invalid")
    //{
       relatedproductscustom.html( data );
    //}
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#salesprice0').fadeIn(800);
        }); 
   }
  });`

Comment: By using the jQuery script above I insert all the price-data from the PHP script into a specific div tag ID "salesprice0". What I want is of course to put each product´s price data into the correct div tag IDs.

Comment: Just to make it clear I have followed your advice and the data from the PHP "calculator" is correctly returned like (id1:price1:discount1,id2:price2:discount2,id3:price3:discount3)
So the only thing I now cannot figure out is to actually use your javascript split by comma function and insert the prices in the div IDs where they belong. I hope I´m not too difficult to understand:)

Comment: Success!! I did it..
Considering I have never coded jQuery this feels like a huge accomplishment for me:)
I will clean up the code and show you the results shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery that made it all happen:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {productIDs:relatedproductsdata.products},
        url: "/CustomCodes/js/VM/related-creator2.php",
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('.ajaxpris').css('display','none');
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {

             jQuery('.ajaxpris').fadeIn(800);   
             var resultsTest = data.split("|");
             i=0;
             jQuery.each(resultsTest, function(idx, value){       
             var resultsTest2 = value.split(":");
             ii=0
             jQuery.each(resultsTest2, function(idx, value1){           
             var resultsValue = value1;
             if (ii==0) {
             var elements1 = "#donotexist"+i;
             }
             else if (ii==1) {
             var elements1 = "#productsalesprice"+i;
             }
             else if (ii==2) {
             var elements1 = "#productdiscount"+i;
             var elements2 = "#productdiscounthaeddiv"+i;
                if (value1!=="0%") {
                jQuery(elements2).css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(800);
                }
             }
             var newdiv = jQuery('<span>',{class:'pricesajax', text:value1});
             jQuery(elements1).append( newdiv  );
             ii++
             });              
         i++    
         });      
       });
    }
});
```